# Keeps booting into emergency mode, swap errors

Tags: 18.04

Moved my media server over to a new case last nigth and ever since it will only boot into emergency mode. I am also getting "failed to activate swap /swapfile" error as posted here. 
I have a 120 GB M2 SSD as the system drive with 2 partitions. I also have a HDD that has my media files on it.

[image: /swapfile]

Here is output of cat /etc/fstab - I know it's wrong - but it is in read only mode. I also don't know how to find the UUID of the extra HDD

[image: cat /etc/fstab]

I know there is likely more info needed - please let me know

Edited `/etc/fstab`:
[image: Edited /etc/fstab]

Updated `lsblk`:
[image: updated lsblk]

Updated fstab:
[image: Updated fstab]

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
lsblk -f
```

to find the UUID (it will list all partitions) and

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

to mount the root partition in read/write mode.

Here an example for a correct fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                                       
PARTLABEL=UbuntuStudio1804      /                   ext4    errors=remount-ro    0       1
PARTLABEL=Swap                  none                swap    sw                   0       0
PARTLABEL=ESP1                  /boot/efi           vfat    umask=0077           0       1
PARTLABEL=DATA                  /media/DATA         ext4    rw,noexec            0       2
PARTLABEL=data                  /media/data         ext4    rw,noexec            0       2
PARTLABEL=StudioBackUp          /media/backup       ext4    rw,noexec            0       2
/dev/disk/by-label/archiv       /media/archiv       ext4    rw,noexec,nofail     0       0
```

I use PARTLABEL instead of UUID because this is better readable, the important thing I want to show you here is the order of fstab-lines, that's relevant, fstab-lines are processed in line-order, so you must mount `/` first! Also note that lines starting with a `#` are comments and not processed.

Comment: Yes the lsblk only shows the sda drive

Comment: Should there be any output for the mount line?

Comment: OK I added the edited /etc/fstab in original post. Should I jsut take out the /dev/sdc1 since it is not showing in lsblk?

Comment: internal HDD x xx

Comment: Still boots tod emergency mode - Ctrl-D doesn't do anything

Comment: If `lsblk` doesn't list the drive, it's probably not connected properly, you should check the connectors. prepend the related fstab-line with a `#` first and try if you can boot then.

Comment: I did prepend with a # - I'll check connectors

Comment: ..... power cord was loose

Comment: Avoid using device names (like `/dev/sdc1`) in fstab-lines, using UUID is much more robust.

Comment: Now it bumped the other drive to sdb - I'm noticing sdb2 isn't mounted to /home? That's what I put in fstab...

Comment: Yup - I read about that - I didn't actually add that line is fstab

Comment: I don't see a line for your root-partition in your updated fstab. Wrong picture?

Comment: It's the first line - it may entirely be worng

Comment: The first line is the boot partition and the second is supposed to be the system partition? All on the M2 SSD - but in lsblk it's not mounted to /home

Comment: Still missing line for `/`-partition. Do you see the empty line under `# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation`, there you have to place the line for `/`. Also comment out the last line with `/dev/sdc1`.

Comment: Ah - yes - I was just looking at that. I've updated the fstab above

Comment: YES! It worked!!

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: The line for `/` is at the wrong place. `/` has to be mounted first I'll add an example in my answer.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer with a click on the check-mark (left side of the answer) then. I gave you an upvote as well for your always quick responses with useful information.